# Multiple data grab from myScanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to grab and store (coordinate1,x1,y1) at the same time .

Here is what I am trying to have happen when someone enteres 2,3:

coordinate = (2,3)

x1=2

y1=3

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class LinearSlopeFinder {
      public static void main(String[]args){
         double x1, y1 ;


         Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("    What is the first set of cordinants? ... ");
         String coordinate1 = myScanner.next();//this is the only thing 

                 //it stores

         x1= myScanner.nextInt();//need this from myScanner
         y1= myScanner.nextInt();//need this from myScanner


         System.out.println("your coordinates are " + coordinate1);
         System.out.println("x1 is "+ x1 );

    }
}
```

now trying to split but still getting an error

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class LinearSlopeFinder {
public static void main(String[]args){
    int x1, y1, x2, y2, n1, equation, slope ;

    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("    What is the first set of cordinants? ... ");
    String coordinate1 = myScanner.nextLine();
    String coordinates[] = coordinate1.split(",");
    x1 = coordinates[0];
    y1 = coordinates[1];

    System.out.println("your cordinants are " + cordinant1);
    System.out.println("x1 is "+ x1 );

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the line `myScanner.nextLine()` and save it to `coordiante1`.
Split the `coordiante1` using `,` as delimiter (`String#split`). Cast(`Integer#parseInt`) & Assign 0th index to `x1` and 1st index to `y1`.

Comment: Thanks, I looked up spliting but am having problems actually splitting here is what i have tried     int coordinate1;
    int[] temp;
   
    
    String delimiter = ",";
    
    temp = int.split(delimiter);
    
    for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
      System.out.println(temp[i]);

Comment: `coordinate = myScanner.nextLine(); String coordinates[] = coordinate.split(","); int x1 = coordiates[0]; int y1 = coordinates[1];`

Comment: mport java.util.Scanner;

public class LinearSlopeFinder {
 public static void main(String[]args){
  int x1, y1, x2, y2, n1, equation, slope ;
  
  Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.print("    What is the first set of cordinants? ... ");
     String coordinate1 = myScanner.nextLine();
  String coordinates[] = coordinate1.split(",");
     x1 = coordinates[0];
  y1 = coordinates[1];
  
  System.out.println("your cordinants are " + cordinant1);
  System.out.println("x1 is "+ x1 );
  
 }
}

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 coordinate cannot be resolved
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int
 cordinant1 cannot be resolved to a variable

 at LinearSlopeFinder.main(LinearSlopeFinder.java:11)

Comment: @PythagorasPi: you need to cast String to int. `Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0]);`

Comment: Itj is not allowing me to keep coordinate1 in the print command : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 cordinant1 cannot be resolved to a variable

 at LinearSlopeFinder.main(LinearSlopeFinder.java:15)

Comment: @PythagorasPi: compile first and fix the error. Fix the `typo` in `coordinate1`, not `cordiant1`

Comment: You Are Awesome , Sorry about that .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want your input to look like, but there are all kinds of ways to use the Scanner class.  Check out the API documentation to get a better idea about how this class works: [J2SE6 Scanner API Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)